# check two array's exact sequence with grep

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, grep

I want to write a **bash** script to compare two array with each other
for example suppose:

```
array1 = ( item1 item2 item3 item4)

array2 = ( item2 item1 item3 item4)
```

I am going to check this array to find out how many items in array2 is **exactly** at the same place in array1.

In this example **item3** and **item4** have the same index.
Is there any one to help me how to do this with "**grep**" command in bash?

Comment: Why would you want to use `grep` for this? (Why would you think that you even *could* use `grep` for this?)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a job for `grep`.

```
i=0
same=0
while (( i < ${#array1[@]} && i < ${#array2[@]} )); do
    (( ${array1[i]} == ${array2[i]} && same++ ))
    (( i++ ))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk it is one liner:

```
array1=( item1 item2 item3 item4 )
array2=( item2 item1 item3 item4 )
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=NR;next} a[$1]==FNR' <(printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}")
item3
item4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `grep` this should do.

```
#!/bin/bash
array1=(item1 item2 item3 item4)
array2=(item2 item1 item3 item4)
paste <(for f in "${array1[@]}" ; do echo "$f" ; done) <(for f in "${array2[@]}" ; do echo "$f" ; done) | grep $'^\\([^\t]*\\)\t\\1' | cut -f 1
```

Output:

```
item3
item4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the indices of the first array and compare them to the second array to find the similarities.

You can expand to the list of array indices using parameter expansion like `${!array[@]}`.

```
for i in ${!array1[@]}; do
    [[ ${array1[$i]} == ${array2[$i]} ]] && same+=("[$i]=${array1[$i]}")
done
echo "Same indices: ${same[@]}"
```